# Define word at the end of a string

Tags: javascript, html

How do I replace a word at the end of a string? for instance,
I fetch some data from json file as this, `${groupNames.subNames[0].Nicknames[0].Name}`
Now I can do var coolNames = groupNames.subNames[0].Nicknames[0]; and use it like coolNames.Name.
However if I do var coolNickname = Name; and use it like groupNames.subNames[0].Nicknames[0].coolNickname it won't output it.

Comment: You can use `coolNickname = 'Name'` and  `groupNames.subNames[0].Nicknames[0][coolNickname]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you meant to ask was

#### How do I use a variable to specify a property name within an existing object?

Don't call it a "string", because it gives the wrong impression of what you are trying to do.

- `groupNames` is an object.
- `groupNames.subNames` is an property of `groupNames`, whose key is `subNames`. It happens to be an array,
- and so on.

#### Whenever you are selecting a property within an object, you have two ways to do it

1. `groupNames.subNames`

This way is more concise and therefore the usual way. However you are forced to say `subNames` explicitly, and can't make it a string.

2. `groupNames["subNames"]`

This way is slightly more ugly *but* allows you to put a variable instead of explicitly saying `subNames`.

As @shuo says in the comments, you can take this second approach to your problem:

```
var coolNickname = 'Name'; 

console.log(`His name is ${groupNames.subNames[0].Nicknames[0][coolNickname]}.`)
```